# Parallel queries over different connections in a single transactions

Tags: sql-server, tedious, node-mssql

I have a scenario, to implement workflow management. There is an option, with parallel gateway, two (or more) branches of tasks can be executed on parallel. The task essentially means some DB operation.

**Problem:**

Considering a sandbox type of execution, I need to revert the whole thing if anything goes wrong. So everything has to be done under a single transaction. But it doesn't fit when I have a couple of parallel task/db queries.

**Analysis:**

As I am using node-pool (used under node-mssql) for connection pooling. So, for a transaction to start, we acquire a single connection and run subsequent queries in the same. For another query to run in parallel, we need another connection from pool that doesn't share the transaction or resource of the first connection.

Is there any way to make it happen? Any kind of help or discussion is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in SQL Server where you can bind a session to another, and that means they share the same transaction and lock space, but the feature is deprecated and might be removed in the feature.

The idea is you get a token from one session using [sp_getbindtoken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getbindtoken-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and bind another session to this first using [sp_bindsession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-bindsession-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You'll have to experiment a bit to see if it works for you scenario.

The replacement feature suggested in the docs linked to above is [Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-2017). Again you'll have to do some experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be using the [unit of work pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) on the nodeside.

Unfortunately I don't know if a module already exists that would help you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, which I would **NOT** recommend is using distributed transactions.  SQL Server supports enroling in distributed transaction.  So you could register each db task into a distributed transaction and at the end commit\rollback it.

You would normally use distributed transactinos to coordinate transactions across multiple transaction datastores however it would also work with multiple connections to the same database but I do not think its a good approach.

To do this you will need a distrbuted transaction coordinator ([MSDTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Distributed_Transaction_Coordinator) does this on Windows) and it gets complex and can have performance issues.